# Drupal as Framework

Tags: 7, entities

I am working on a project where I decided to use Drupal as the backend, but I didn't wanted to use anything else, but the entities API. The project is working like a charm and everything is working smooth.

I am a bit batter by the fact, that even when not using nodes, I can not disable the node core module and therefore I still have a ton of extra tables I will never use. Some time ago I remember people talking about "small core".

What happen to that?

Comment: Basically became Drupal 8..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 7, the Node module is always enabled, even if the profile you are using for installing Drupal doesn't actually declare it as dependency. See the content of [minimal.info](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/profiles/minimal/minimal.info?h=7.x) and [standard.info](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/profiles/standard/standard.info?h=7.x).
In Drupal 8, profiles requiring the Node module need to explicitly define their dependencies from it. (See the content of [standard.info.yml](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/profiles/standard/standard.info.yml?h=8.1.x).)

If you don't need to use the Node module, you need to create a Drupal 8 profile that doesn't declare the Node module as its dependency. The necessary changes to Drupal 7 that allows decoupling the rest of the core modules from the Node module will not be backported, so your only chance is using Drupal 8 with a profile that doesn't depend from the Node module.